# Allowing Users To Create Custom Paragraphs With Some Static Values In PHP

Tags: php

Lets say here's the static string:

```
$name = "John";
$age = 37;
```

Now, let's say a user is entering the following values in the Textarea:

```
His name is {name}. His age is {age}
```

He may also type:

```
{name} is his name. {age} is his age.
```

Now, when the user submits the form, PHP should set those strings to those specific positions.

e.g output should be like:

```
His name is John. His age is 37

John is his name. 37 is his age.
```

Comment: This is not a question, it's just a wish list. You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. This is not a free coding service.

Comment: Can you at least tell me what it's called? I have no idea about creating such templates... All I need is a tip...

Comment: Placeholders? Templating?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since you didn't provide specific details of the problem, I can only speculate that you might want this:

```php
<?php

$name = "John";
$age = 37;

$userInput1 = "His name is {name}. His age is {age}";
$userInput2 = "{name} is his name. {age} is his age.";

$result1 = str_replace("{name}", $name, $userInput1);
$result1 = str_replace("{age}", $age, $result1);

$result2 = str_replace("{name}", $name, $userInput2);
$result2 = str_replace("{age}", $age, $result2);

echo "$result1<br>$result2";
```

This is just a very simple text replacement.

According to what you said, let the user input from the textarea and then pass it to php and output the result. This is a demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="a.php" method="post">
        <textarea name="text_from_textarea"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php

$name = "John";
$age = 37;

$userInput = $_POST["text_from_textarea"];

$result = str_replace("{name}", $name, $userInput);
$result = str_replace("{age}", $age, $result);

echo "$result";
```